# Are Modern Browsers susceptible to HTTP Splitting Attacks

Tags: security, http-headers

I am trying to imitate the HTTP Splitting attack on my machine.
For that I wrote this php code:

```
<?php
header("Location: " . $_GET['page']);
?>
```

And then I enter the following URL:

```
http://localhost/webgoat/httpsplitting.php?page=index%0aContent-Length:%200%0a%0aHTTP/1.1%20200%20OK%0aContent-Type:%20text/html%0aContent-Length:%2017%0a%0a<html>Hacked</html>
```

But then also when I intercept the request using webscarab, I see that these headers are not included in the web server's response.

Additionally I saw in wireshark that the LF sequence (i.e. %0a) is not converted into its ASCII format and is used as a string and not as a line feed.

So, I came to the deduction that modern web browsers are not susceptible to this attack. Am I correct ??

Comment: Suits better for security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks...I have asked this question there also. :)

Comment: [Please do not cross post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/241749) - thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security and was cross-posted here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47224/are-modern-servers-susceptible-to-http-splitting-attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attack is not only in the browser level, but also in caching and proxy servers! So, even if the browsers added protection, it might not be enough.

See the paper (search for proxy, for example):

http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/425593

And more recent one:

http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/425593